# I want to transfer the label output from one page to another page in aspx/aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net

This aspx source at the bottom is my label in Order.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

My coding in Order.aspx.cs to achieve the lblGrandTotal (Label) output is

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double Price = 0;
        double Tax = 0;
        double TotalPriceAir = 0;
        double TotalPricePro = 0;
        double GrandTotal = 0;

        btn_ViewOrder.Visible = true;
        Button3.Visible = true;
        

        if (RadioButtonAir2019one.Checked == true)
        {
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxAir2019.Text);
            Price = Price * 739;
            Tax = Price * 0.07;
            TotalPriceAir = Price + Tax;
            GrandTotal = TotalPriceAir + TotalPricePro;
            lblSubTotalAir2019.Text = "Subtotal: $" + Price;
            lblGSTAir.Text = "GST (7%): " + Tax;
            lblTotalPriceAir.Text = "Total Price: " + TotalPriceAir;
            lblGrandTotal.Text = "Grand Total: " + GrandTotal;
        }
        if (RadioButtonAir2019two.Checked == true)
        {
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxAir2019.Text);
            Price = Price * 739;
            Tax = Price * 0.07;
            TotalPriceAir = Price + Tax;
            GrandTotal = TotalPriceAir + TotalPricePro;
            lblSubTotalAir2019.Text = "Subtotal: $" + Price;
            lblGSTAir.Text = "GST (7%): " + Tax;
            lblTotalPriceAir.Text = "Total Price: " + TotalPriceAir;
            lblGrandTotal.Text = "Grand Total: " + GrandTotal;
        }
        if (RadioButtonAir2020one.Checked == true)
        {
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxAir2020.Text);
            Price = Price * 989;
            Tax = Price * 0.07;
            TotalPriceAir = Price + Tax;
            GrandTotal = TotalPriceAir + TotalPricePro;
            lblSubTotalAir2020.Text = "Subtotal: $" + Price;
            lblGSTAir.Text = "GST (7%): " + Tax;
            lblTotalPriceAir.Text = "Total Price: " + TotalPriceAir;
            lblGrandTotal.Text = "Grand Total: " + GrandTotal;
        }
        if (RadioButtonAir2020two.Checked == true)
        {
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxAir2020.Text);
            Price = Price * 989;
            Tax = Price * 0.07;
            TotalPriceAir = Price + Tax;
            GrandTotal = TotalPriceAir + TotalPricePro;
            lblSubTotalAir2020.Text = "Subtotal: $" + Price;
            lblGSTAir.Text = "GST (7%): " + Tax;
            lblTotalPriceAir.Text = "Total Price: " + TotalPriceAir;
            lblGrandTotal.Text = "Grand Total: " + GrandTotal;
        }
        if (RadioButtonPro2020one.Checked == true)
        {
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxPro2020.Text);
            Price = Price * 1219;
            Tax = Price * 0.07;
            TotalPricePro = Price + Tax;
            GrandTotal = TotalPriceAir + TotalPricePro;
            lblSubTotalPro2020.Text = "Subtotal: $" + Price;
            lblGSTPro.Text = "GST (7%): " + Tax;
            lblTotalPricePro.Text = "Total Price: " + TotalPricePro;
            lblGrandTotal.Text = "Grand Total: " + GrandTotal;
        }
        if (RadioButtonPro2020two.Checked == true)
        {
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxPro2020.Text);
            Price = Price * 1219;
            Tax = Price * 0.07;
            TotalPricePro = Price + Tax;
            GrandTotal = TotalPriceAir + TotalPricePro;
            lblSubTotalPro2020.Text = "Subtotal: $" + Price;
            lblGSTPro.Text = "GST (7%): " + Tax;
            lblTotalPricePro.Text = "Total Price: " + TotalPricePro;
            lblGrandTotal.Text = "Grand Total: " + GrandTotal;
        }
        if (RadioButtonPro2021one.Checked == true)
        {
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxPro2021.Text);
            Price = Price * 1478;
            Tax = Price * 0.07;
            TotalPricePro = Price + Tax;
            GrandTotal = TotalPriceAir + TotalPricePro;
            lblSubTotalPro2021.Text = "Subtotal: $" + Price;
            lblGSTPro.Text = "GST (7%): " + Tax;
            lblTotalPricePro.Text = "Total Price: " + TotalPricePro;
            lblGrandTotal.Text = "Grand Total: " + GrandTotal;
        }
        if (RadioButtonPro2021two.Checked == true)
        {
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxPro2021.Text);
            Price = Price * 1478;
            Tax = Price * 0.07;
            TotalPricePro = Price + Tax;
            GrandTotal = TotalPriceAir + TotalPricePro;
            lblSubTotalPro2021.Text = "Subtotal: $" + Price;
            lblGSTPro.Text = "GST (7%): " + Tax;
            lblTotalPricePro.Text = "Total Price: " + TotalPricePro;
            lblGrandTotal.Text = "Grand Total: " + GrandTotal;
        }
```

and I want both lblGrandTotal and lblGrandTotal2 (Label) to have this output but lblGrandTotal2 is in another web form which is Checkout.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal2" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

In Order.aspx.cs i have tried to transfer the lblGrandTotal output to Checkout.aspx.cs but its not working

```
 protected void btn_Payment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Checkout.aspx");
        Response.Redirect("Checkout.aspx?id=" + lblGrandTotal.Text);

    }
```

after clicking the Payment button it will go to another page which is Checkout.aspx and i have key in this code to try to link the labels but its not working

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblGrandTotal2.Text = Request.QueryString["id"];
    }
```

**I want to achieve both lblGrandTotal and lblGrandTotal2 labels to have the same output in different web forms.**

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your server side code segment that demonstrates your attempt to resolve this yourself, and then explain at what point you're encountering a problem.

Comment: We need to know how you set that label in code, and also how are you jumping or using navigation to get to the 2nd web form. Without this information, we are quite much in the dark here, and can only guess.  The code that sets the value of the first label  thus could probably set session() value at the same time, then when you navigate to the 2nd form, you can set that label to the same value. Or you could pass parameters, or you could use post-back URL,and on page load in the 2nd page, you are free to grab ANY control from that previous form. Dozen ways for this based on what you have now

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal
Apologise for not making it clear enough. Hopefully after I edit it will be easier for you to understand Thank you

Comment: @devlincarnate 
Apologise for not making it clear enough. Hopefully after I edit it will be easier for you to understand Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you have should work. However, this don't look correct:

```
protected void btn_Payment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Checkout.aspx");
    Response.Redirect("Checkout.aspx?id=" + lblGrandTotal.Text);

}
```

Should it not be:

```
protected void btn_Payment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Checkout.aspx?id=" + lblGrandTotal.Text);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, its working :)

Comment: Keep in mind, while you had to two lines of code? Any time you use a Response.Redirect, the code that follows AFTER that line of code DOES NOT execute!! - it in effect is a exit sub, or a "break" to exit from the current routine. I mean, if you jumping to a new page, then no further code execution need occur, and in fact does not. So when you had the two lines of code, the first would execute and exit that function - the 2nd line never would run as a result.